# Получить ID следующего и предыдущего поста в данной категории

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть ID выведенного поста. Нужно получить ID следующего поста и ID предыдущего поста в этой же категории.
Это нужно для создания пагинации в определенной рубрике постов.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Для начала надо для *себя* определить, что такое "следующий" и "предыдущий".

Comment: написать запрос, который будет брать 1 значение назад и 1 значение вперёд

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/next_post_link